# Dynamic Way to Insert Data into SQLite Table When Column Counts Change

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working on a script using SQLite where there is a flux in the number of columns that are available to be inserted into a table I am creating to later do a join on.

The table I am created to insert the data into has 97 columns, the data coming in from my feed can range from around 80 all the way up to that 97th column.

The error I get is `SQLITE_ERROR: table allPositionsTable has 97 columns but 80 values were supplied` and is the one I am trying to avoid by figuring out a way where this doesn't happen.

Are there any workarounds or tricks I can use to have SQLite function so that it will always include the columns where there is no data for them or dynamically not include them so the error goes away?

Comment: If you're only inserting 80 values into a row, only insert those 80 columns instead of 97 (And make sure the ones you're leaving out can have null values).

Comment: @Shawn so if there are extra columns what would happen? Since I can't predict what the number of columns will be coming in.

Comment: There's this: https://execsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metacommands.html#import

Comment: Columns you don't include in the list of ones being inserted are filled with a default value if present in the table definition, or nulls otherwise. If one of these columns is defined as being `NOT NULL` that would of course be an error. Hence not wanting to omit any such columns.

Comment: Waitaminute... you **do** know how to specify just the particular columns you're providing values for when inserting a row, right?

Comment: @Shawn

Replying to your first comment:Thank you for the detail. So what I would need to do would be to include less properties in the `CREATE TABLE...` statement. Then my insert statement (`INSERT INTO allPositionsTable SELECT * FROM allPositions`) would work?

Replying to your second comment: I do know how to specify what I want to insertr but whenever this feed runs I am not sure which columns are going to be available. Which is why I cannot specify actually.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to get with that, but no, I don't think you know about specifying columns with inserts. If you have a table with, say, three columns `a`, `b` and `c`, and want to insert a row with values only known for columns `a` and `c`, you do something like `INSERT INTO mytable(a, c) VALUES ('a value', 'c value');`. `b`, which is left out, is assigned null. That's the sort of thing you need to be doing.

Comment: Not what you asked about, but it should be noted that in a well formed, properly normalized database, that represents any kind of real world data, it is almost impossible to have a legitimate need for a table with 97 columns. What data is this table supposed to be storing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error I get is `SQLITE_ERROR: table allPositionsTable has 97
>   columns but 80 values were supplied` and is the one I am trying to
>   avoid by figuring out a way where this doesn't happen.

This happens because you are using the default column list (i.e. by not specifying the columns into which the values are to be placed)

That is you would be coding the equivalent of `INSERT INTO your_table VALUES(.......`
so in the absence of a list of columns you are saying that you will provide a value for all columns in the table and hence the message when a value or values are not present.

What you want to do is use `INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_comma_separated_list_of_columns_to_be_inserted) VALUES(.......`

- where *your_table_name* and *your_comma_separated_list_of_columns_to_be_inserted* would be replaced with the appropriate values.

See the highlighted section of the INSERT syntax that can be found at  [SQL As Understood By SQLite - INSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

[image]

and the respective section from the above link is :-

> The first form (with the "VALUES" keyword) creates one or more new
>   rows in an existing table.
>
> If the column-name list after table-name is
>   omitted then the number of values inserted into each row must be the
>   same as the number of columns in the table.
>
> In this case the result of
>   evaluating the left-most expression from each term of the VALUES list
>   is inserted into the left-most column of each new row, and so forth
>   for each subsequent expression.
>
> If a column-name list is specified,
>   then the number of values in each term of the VALUE list must match
>   the number of specified columns.
>
> Each of the named columns of the new
>   row is populated with the results of evaluating the corresponding
>   VALUES expression.
>
> Table columns that do not appear in the column list
>   are populated with the default column value (specified as part of the
>   CREATE TABLE statement), or with NULL if no default value is
>   specified.